# GET[] in while mysqli

Tags: php, button, while-loop

I have been making a shop where all items is on there. I output them in a while loop.

And as you can see in the while is there a button so the user can buy an item. However, why does nothing happen when that `<input type=submit>` button is clicked?

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `shop` WHERE type='hoved' order by item ASC") or die(mysqli_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<img src='img/".$row['type']."/".$row['item'].".png' width='130' height='70' style='margin-left: 15px;'/>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<a href='?shop'><input type='submit' style='width: 100px; height: 25px;' name='".$row['id']."' value='".$row['price']."'/></a>";
        echo "<br /><br /><br />";

        if(@$_GET['shop']){
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE `man` SET head = '".$row['item']."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'") or die(mysqli_error());
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use `if(isset($_GET['shop']))` instead of `if(@$_GET['shop'])`

Comment: `echo "<a href='?shop'>` what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: `<a href..><input type="submit" .../></a>` what's this consruct supposed to do? (it doesn't do that ;-)) The if-construct within the while loop suggest a misconception about how php works. php is executed on the server while the action triggered by the anchor/button is client side stuff. Better work through another tutorial.

Comment: Guys insted for hate on me, can you help me. I am new on PHP so i am 50% what i doing...

Comment: @KhaledMoussa Check out my post below. It simplifies what you are trying to do so that the problem becomes more encapsulated, uses only a single array, and allows you to issue simplified SQL to INSERT Items to an intermediate table that can represent User Carts (rowId, userId, itemId - query all users for single item or all items for single user)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `shop` WHERE type='hoved' ORDER BY item ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
     echo "<img src='img/".$row['type']."/".$row['item'].".png' width='130' height='70' style='margin-left: 15px;'/>";
     echo "<br />";
     echo "<form action='' method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' value='" . $row['id']. "' name='shop'>
    <input type='submit' style='width: 100px; height: 25px;' value='".$row['price']."'/></form>";
    echo "<br /><br /><br />";
    if(isset($_GET['shop'])){
        $id = $_GET['shop'];
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `man` SET head = '".$row['item']."' WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysqli_error());
    }else{
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can only have 1 submit button for each form in PHP. When Submit is clicked, the `action` property inside the `<form action="processForm.php"></form>` calls either a new script or function.

Since you are creating a submit button for each element in your shop, you would also need to create a new form tag for every button.

A better alternative is to use `<input type="button" onclick="loadItemToCart($itemId)" />` which would call a function to insert an element into an array representing your users cart. When the User chooses to click continue or check-out, then you can send the entire array of items to the next script that will process the order, rather than each element individual.

You can do this using the following tag:

```
<input type="hidden" value="itemsArray" name="cart" />
```

This should be the easiest approach to your problem.